# Generating unique/random serial numbers using group_by in R using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I would like to generate unique numbers (serial or random) grouped by certain columns using R.

A sample dataset is provided below

```
fact_code  style_         item             buyer
1206       -23            LADIES TANK TOP  652
1206       -23            LADIES TANK TOP  652
1206       -23            LADIES TANK TOP  652
1214       593935_592435  SS T-SHIRT       254
1214       593935_592435  SS T-SHIRT       254 
1214       593935_592435  SS T-SHIRT       254
7022       1572472        T-SHIRT          338
7022       1572472        T-SHIRT          338
7022       1572472        T-SHIRT          338
```

Using the data above, I would like to create a variable, for example, style_serial that looks like this:

```
fact_code  style_         item             buyer style_serial
1206       -23            LADIES TANK TOP  652   1
1206       -23            LADIES TANK TOP  652   1
1206       -23            LADIES TANK TOP  652   1   
1214       593935_592435  SS T-SHIRT       254   2
1214       593935_592435  SS T-SHIRT       254   2 
1214       593935_592435  SS T-SHIRT       254   2
7022       1572472        T-SHIRT          338   3
7022       1572472        T-SHIRT          338   3
7022       1572472        T-SHIRT          338   3
```

That is, create a variable that assumes unique value grouped by the columns fact_code, style_, item and buyer. I have tried the following R code using the `dplyr` package:

```
df <- df %>%
dplyr::group_by(fact_code, style_, buyer) %>%
dplyr::mutate(style_serial = 1:n())
```

where `df` is the name of the above sample data-frame. But it gives me an unexpected output:

```
fact_code  style_         item             buyer style_serial
1206       -23            LADIES TANK TOP  652   1
1206       -23            LADIES TANK TOP  652   2
1206       -23            LADIES TANK TOP  652   3   
1214       593935_592435  SS T-SHIRT       254   1
1214       593935_592435  SS T-SHIRT       254   2 
1214       593935_592435  SS T-SHIRT       254   3
7022       1572472        T-SHIRT          338   1
7022       1572472        T-SHIRT          338   2
7022       1572472        T-SHIRT          338   3
```

I wouldn't mind if the style_serial is randomized set of integers, so that the data would look like this:

```
fact_code  style_         item             buyer style_serial
1206       -23            LADIES TANK TOP  652   10
1206       -23            LADIES TANK TOP  652   10
1206       -23            LADIES TANK TOP  652   10   
1214       593935_592435  SS T-SHIRT       254   2
1214       593935_592435  SS T-SHIRT       254   2 
1214       593935_592435  SS T-SHIRT       254   2
7022       1572472        T-SHIRT          338   100
7022       1572472        T-SHIRT          338   100
7022       1572472        T-SHIRT          338   100
```

To generate the above table, I run the following `R` code:

```
df <- df %>%
dplyr::group_by(fact_code, style_, buyer) %>%
dplyr::mutate(style_serial = sample(1:6000, n(), replace = FALSE))
```

However, I am not able to get the desired output.

The main objective is to create a variable in this case, style_serial, which assumes unique values grouped by certain number of columns i.e. in this case fact_code, style_, item and buyer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `group_indices` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(style_serial = sample(6000)[group_indices(.,fact_code, style_, buyer)])
# fact_code        style_            item buyer style_serial
#1      1206           -23 LADIES TANK TOP   652         5778
#2      1206           -23 LADIES TANK TOP   652         5778
#3      1206           -23 LADIES TANK TOP   652         5778
#4      1214 593935_592435      SS T-SHIRT   254          998
#5      1214 593935_592435      SS T-SHIRT   254          998
#6      1214 593935_592435      SS T-SHIRT   254          998
#7      7022       1572472         T-SHIRT   338         3018
#8      7022       1572472         T-SHIRT   338         3018
#9      7022       1572472         T-SHIRT   338         3018
```

NOTE: the numbers are `random`ized with `sample`, if we don't need it, then remove the `sample` part

```
df %>%
  mutate(style_serial = group_indices(.,fact_code, style_, buyer))
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
v1 <- with(df, do.call(paste, df[1:3]))
df$style_serial <-  match(v1, unique(v1))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(fact_code = c(1206L, 1206L, 1206L, 1214L, 1214L, 
1214L, 7022L, 7022L, 7022L), style_ = c("-23", "-23", "-23", 
"593935_592435", "593935_592435", "593935_592435", "1572472", 
"1572472", "1572472"), item = c("LADIES TANK TOP", "LADIES TANK TOP", 
"LADIES TANK TOP", "SS T-SHIRT", "SS T-SHIRT", "SS T-SHIRT", 
"T-SHIRT", "T-SHIRT", "T-SHIRT"), buyer = c(652L, 652L, 652L, 
254L, 254L, 254L, 338L, 338L, 338L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: Adding `group_indices` to my list of "extremely situational functions." I had no idea this existed, very slick.

Answer (score 2):

Fully `dplyr` solution, making a lookup table and joining it onto the base table.

```r
serial_df <- df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(fact_code, style_, buyer) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise() %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(style_serial = row_number())

dplyr::left_join(df, serial_df)
#> Joining, by = c("fact_code", "style_", "buyer")
#>   fact_code        style_            item buyer style_serial
#> 1      1206           -23 LADIES TANK TOP   652            1
#> 2      1206           -23 LADIES TANK TOP   652            1
#> 3      1206           -23 LADIES TANK TOP   652            1
#> 4      1214 593935_592435      SS T-SHIRT   254            2
#> 5      1214 593935_592435      SS T-SHIRT   254            2
#> 6      1214 593935_592435      SS T-SHIRT   254            2
#> 7      7022       1572472         T-SHIRT   338            3
#> 8      7022       1572472         T-SHIRT   338            3
#> 9      7022       1572472         T-SHIRT   338            3
```

If you want it as a "one-liner":

```r
df <- df %>% dplyr::left_join(
  df %>%
    dplyr::group_by(fact_code, style_, buyer) %>% 
    dplyr::summarise() %>% 
    dplyr::ungroup() %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(style_serial = row_number())
  )
#> Joining, by = c("fact_code", "style_", "buyer")
#>   fact_code        style_            item buyer style_serial
#> 1      1206           -23 LADIES TANK TOP   652            1
#> 2      1206           -23 LADIES TANK TOP   652            1
#> 3      1206           -23 LADIES TANK TOP   652            1
#> 4      1214 593935_592435      SS T-SHIRT   254            2
#> 5      1214 593935_592435      SS T-SHIRT   254            2
#> 6      1214 593935_592435      SS T-SHIRT   254            2
#> 7      7022       1572472         T-SHIRT   338            3
#> 8      7022       1572472         T-SHIRT   338            3
#> 9      7022       1572472         T-SHIRT   338            3
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rleid` from `data.table`, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
 mutate(style = data.table::rleid(fact_code, style_, item))
```

Answer (score 1):

A way with `dplyr` without additional packages:

```
df %>%
  mutate(
    style_serial = cumsum(
      coalesce(as.numeric(paste0(fact_code, style_, buyer) != lag(paste0(fact_code, style_, buyer))), 1)
      )
  )
```

With `data.table` only:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, style_serial := .GRP, by = .(fact_code, style_, buyer)]
```

Output in both cases:

```
   fact_code        style_          item buyer style_serial
1:      1206           -23 LADIESTANKTOP   652            1
2:      1206           -23 LADIESTANKTOP   652            1
3:      1206           -23 LADIESTANKTOP   652            1
4:      1214 593935_592435     SST-SHIRT   254            2
5:      1214 593935_592435     SST-SHIRT   254            2
6:      1214 593935_592435     SST-SHIRT   254            2
7:      7022       1572472       T-SHIRT   338            3
8:      7022       1572472       T-SHIRT   338            3
9:      7022       1572472       T-SHIRT   338            3
```